# starting vagrant box from any virtual machines such as virtualbox through their interface

Tags: hash, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have made package of vagrant box through **vagrant package** command and I want to distribute that newly made vagrant box to every developers currently working in my team. The problem is that I do not want that every developer should install vagrant in it. I just want that the vagrant box which I have shared will get open through the user interface of virtual box or any virtual machine currently installed.

how could I achieve this goal??

Here is my error when I just try to open the vagrant.box through the virtual box

```html
enter Failed to open the optical disk file /home/sandeep/vagrant image/ldapclient.box.

Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/sandeep/vagrant image/ldapclient.box' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)code here
```

Comment: I think the hash value of the vagrant box and the ubuntu os which we choose while creating new virtual machine doesn't match

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144780/virtual-box-wont-accept-iso-to-install-os. So you can answer your own question

Comment: @BMW the link which you have provided is for how to launch a new virtual machine inside virtual box.. My problem is how to run a vagrant box through virtualbox through it's ui not through running vagrant up command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `.box` is just a tar file with some metadata and provider specific files inside.

It's not a Virtualbox supported format.

In your case, I'm not sure why you even use Vagrant (since you can just use Virtualbox's export function). But if you insist, all you have to do is to extract the files from the .box file and import into Virtualbox the `.ovf` & `.vmdk` files

### Update:

Step by step guide how to extract `.box` file and run it in Virtualbox:

1. Extracting: `.box` is just a tar/tar.gz/zip file, so use utilities like 7-zip, unzip or tar to extract the files (depends on your OS).
2. After extracting you should see folder structure which is similar to the following one (I'm using `ubuntu\trusty64` box as example):

   `.
   |____14.04
   | |____virtualbox
   | | |____.vagrant
   | | |____box-disk1.vmdk
   | | |____box.ovf
   | | |____metadata.json
   | | |____Vagrantfile
   |____metadata_url`

as you can see, `box` format is just a container to provider specific data with some additional meta data that helps Vagrant with versioning and so on. The key files here are `.ovf` and `.vmdk` which Virtualbox supports.

3. Open Virtualbox and in the File menu choose Import Appliance (this is in OS X. In your OS it might be a bit different)
4. Point the import wizard to the `.ovf` file from your extracted directory and proceed with the import.
5. Some machine details will be shown now and you can change some of them (Memory, CPU, etc)
6. Proceed with the import - a new virtual machine should appear now in Virtualbox
7. Start the new virtual machine

Comment: can u provide step by step procedure to extract the files from the .box file and import into the virtualbox

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer , you have saved my time and also the time of my developers team :)